# compress specific folder(directory) from folder with tar

Tags: linux, tar, compression

I am trying to use `tar` to compress the subdirectories `/root/folder/folder{1..5}` into a single compressed archive `test1.tar.bz2`. I'm using the following command:

```bsh
tar -cvjf test1.tar.bz2 root/folder/folder{1..5}
```

Unfortunately this is not working and I'm getting the following output:

```
tar: root/folder/folder1: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: root/folder/folder2: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: root/folder/folder3: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: root/folder/folder4: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: root/folder/folder5: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar (child): bzip2: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: Please, whenever possible, post text instead of images.

Comment: In future you should copy and paste the text from a terminal rather than posting a picture, this will use less storage on the server and make it easier for other users to copy the text.

Comment: I updated your question to use text instead of an image. You might also want to use a file name like `test1.tar.bz2` instead of `test1.tar` to reflect the fact that the archive was compressed using the bzip2 algorithm (i.e. using the `-j` flag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a relative path rather than an absolute path.

Change:

```
root/folder/folder{1..5}
```

Too (correct absolute path):

```
/root/folder/folder{1..5}
```

Or (correct relative path):

```
folder/folder{1..5}
```

Explanation:

You are inside of roots home directory (`/root`), so relative paths will be `/root` + `relative_path`, so in your case you're giving `tar` the path `/root/root/folder/folder{1..5}` which does not exist. You can either give the correct relative path (omitting the `root/` at the beginning) or give the absolute path.